# Django - CreateView doesn't save

Tags: python, django

**UPDATE:**

I have deleted action tag from group_create template and now it works just fine. But if smebody wil lexplain how does it works - I will really appreciate

---

I have two type of objects in my model - 'users' and 'groups' .
I successfully made "create" page for "users" with help of CreateView, but for some reason when I am doing very same with "groups" - it doesn't save.
No errors, it simply doesn't create new entry in database after I push submit button.

Here is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from .models import User, Group
from .forms import UserForm, user_form, group_form
from django.shortcuts import get_list_or_404, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.views.generic import UpdateView, CreateView, DetailView, ListView, UpdateView, DeleteView


class user_create(CreateView):
    template_name = "user_create.html"
    form_class = user_form
    success_url = '/users'

class group_create(CreateView):
    template_name = "group_create.html"
    form_class = group_form
    success_url = '/groups'
```

My models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

# Create your models here.

class Group(models.Model):
    #ID, Name, Description, Actions
    groupname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    #To make in name, not objXXX
    def __str__(self):
        return self.groupname

class User(models.Model):
    #username, created, group, actions
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    date_joined = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True)
    #To make in name, not objXXX
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

Forms used for templates:

```
from django import forms
from django.db import models
from .models import User
from .models import Group


class user_form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'group']

class group_form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ['groupname', 'description']
```

And, finally, templates. For user create page:

```
{% block content %}
<form action='.' method='POST'> {% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type='submit' value='Create user'  /> <button><a href="/users">Cancel</a></button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

and group create page:

```
{% block content %}
<form action='.' method='POST'> {% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type='submit' value='Create group'  /> <button><a href="/groups">Cancel</a></button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from users.views import user_show, user_create, user_delete, user_edit, user_list, group_list, group_create, group_edit, group_delete
from django.shortcuts import redirect

urlpatterns = [
    path('', lambda req: redirect('users/')),
    path('groups/', group_list),
    path('groups/create', group_create.as_view(), name='groupcreate'),
    path('groups/<int:id>/edit/', group_edit.as_view(), name='groupedit'),
    path('groups/<int:id>/delete/', group_delete.as_view()),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('users/<int:id>/delete/', user_delete.as_view()),
    path('users/create/', user_create.as_view(), name='create'),
    path('users/', user_list),
    path('users/<int:id>/edit/', user_edit.as_view(), name='edit')
]
```

Comment: Can you also add your urls.py.

Comment: Sure, updated  above